# Update Python 3.6 package from Deadsnakes PPA

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, ppa, python3

I can not seem to update my version of Python 3.6, installed from the [deadsnakes ppa](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=xenial).

`sudo apt-get update` hits the ppa, and `sudo apt-get upgrade` reports no errors.

When I run `apt policy python3.6`, I get:

```
python3.6:
  Installed: 3.6.2-1+xenial1
  Candidate: 3.6.2-1+xenial1
  Version table:
 *** 3.6.2-1+xenial1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The [webpage for the ppa](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=xenial) says the latest version of 3.6 is `3.6.5-1+xenial1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the wrong ppa. The ppa has been changed from

`ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes` to `ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`

We can clearly see this if we look at the technical details of the ppa:
`apt` should look at

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu ...
```

for available packages, not at

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu
```